# scala sort of view collection performance

Tags: scala, sorting, view

I understand, that a 'view' in **scala** is used to not create a copy of collection, as we need a chain of transforms. It is implemented in a lazy way, so the the element is being calculated over all transform as it is accessed.

```
(1 to 1000000).map(x=>x*x).map(_ % 7).take(1000)
```

will create a temporary collection on each step, which is not needed to obtain the result. And it is better to be rewritten as:

```
(1 to 1000000).view.map(x=>x*x).map(_ % 7).take(1000)
```

So the question is: what if we need to sort it on the preliminary step:

```
 (1 to 1000000).sorted.map(x=>x*x).map(_ % 7).take(1000)
```

Is it feasible to add 'view' here:

```
(1 to 1000000).view.sorted.map(x=>x*x).map(_ % 7).take(1000)
```

I'm just wondering if an initial seq is to be resorted on each element access?

Comment: I can't give detailed explanation but it seems like it will be sorted just once. Look at impl of sorted on view `newForced(thisSeq sorted ord).asInstanceOf[This]` and there is the comment for `Forced` class `A fall back which forces everything into a vector and then applies an operation on it. Used for those operations which do not naturally lend themselves to a view`

Comment: Thank you! :) I feel a bit stupid to searching through the spec papers and not looking at the code itself.